# Two different version of D3 in the same page

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to have on the same page D3 charts that are build with different version of D3 (ok, frames are an option, but ideally without them).

What is the best way to have two version of D3 library in the same page (4.x and 3.x) ?

Comment: If this is possible at all you would need to load one version of d3, alias the variable (e.g. `window.d3v3 = window.d3`), then load the second version. I think it is asking for trouble and iframes are the second-best choice (after porting the v3 code to v4).